# Show server errors into html

Tags: django, python-3.x, error-handling, django-rest-framework

I am validating a form that I have to send via ajax, I am using axios to do this, but I'd like to now if is there someway to show the errors that I receive from server into my html, these are the errors I want to show
[image]

I am using django rest-framework in the server side
This is my code

```
axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: `${baseURL}api/users/`,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data : {} // I send the inputs data here
        })
        .then(response => {
            window.location.href = '/success.html';
            console.log(response)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(`It works ${err.message}`);
        })
```

Doing like this, I only can show the message like

> 'It works Request failed with status code 400'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
var errors = {}
...
.then(response => {
    window.location.href = '/success.html';
    console.log(response)
    errors = Object.assign({})
})
.catch(err => {
    errors = Object.assign({}, err.data['error'])
    console.log(`It works ${err.message}`);
})
```

Then you can use this variable to show errors in html like **errors['address']**.